# Do I need new battery charger for Sony Alpha upgrade?

Tags: sony

I'm in the process of upgrading my A200 to a second hand A580. Will I need a different battery charger, or can I continue using the one from my A200?

Answer (score 2):

According to the specifications both cameras use the same battery: **NP-FM500H**. So you can continue to use old batteries and charger.